# MyBatis - Is it possible to perform a delete and insert sequentially?

Tags: spring, mybatis, spring-mybatis

Is possible to use MyBatis to clear rows from a table and then insert more rows immediately afterwards?

I know it is possible to do each step individually with `<delete>` and `<insert>` statements, however in an effort to make things run more quickly it would be nice to have the `<insert>` run immediately after the `<delete>`

Perhaps an `<sql>` tag could encompass the list of queries?

Comment: Maybe you need procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as your jdbc driver supports it. For example on mysql that means you need to enable [`allowMultiQueries`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html).

Not all dbs allow this (for example hsqldb has [limited prepared statements to single queries since 2.0](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#N156DF))